# Background image in a responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have 4 phone images next to each other, with transparent screens. When the browser's screensize is changed, the phones come closer to each other.

There should be a background image visible through the screens of the phones, but I can't use a background-image for the container and then have each phonescreen transparent, because then one phone will show another one underneath it, as demonstrated here:

http://jsbin.com/ozoyoc/1/

What else I've tried:

1. Put the container background-image in each *phone-div*, didn't work, it seems that the alignment with *background-position* in percentage doesn't *clip* the correct part of the image when resizing the browser window (*)
2. Put a *div* in each phone-*li*, which represented the screen. Couldn't offset the image to the correct position for each phone because the % would be relative to the *parent element size*, which is the *li* and not the *container*

Can this be implemented in CSS or will I have to look at Javascript to set the correct image offset?

**edit:**
* (1) To clarify, in this fiddle the position of the *window moving*-div does show the correct part of the image based on its position. Maybe this is because it's specified in *absolute px* instead of *percentages* ? http://jsfiddle.net/XjCCK/39/

```
.moving {
 left: left,
 top: top,
 backgroundPositionX: -left,
 backgroundPositionY: -top
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be an idea to add the same image as background for each phone `div`?

Comment: @Steeven that's what I tried in (1.), but the image didn't update when resizing. The phone should show the correct part of the image based on the phone's position.

Comment: Okay, so to clear it up: You wan't to show the part of the background through the screen, that is behind the phone. But if two phones are overlapping you *don't* want to see the frame of the phone behind. I find it quite unintuitive though that you in this way can see "through" the phone in the back. Or please correct me, if I have misunderstood it.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood it. The phones should aways show the background-image (the green bubbles). Option 1 didn't work because e.g. the iPhone would show an incorrect part of the bubbles (not enough to the right, not enough to the bottom), the background-position would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `background-attachment: fixed;` to position the inner background (droplets in your case) properly, and then clip it using top/left/right/bottom.

```
.iphone {
  /* needs to have a position value other than 'static' for clipping below */
  position: absolute;

  /* untouched rules */
  width: 177.6px;
  height: 411px;
  top: 15.2%;
  left: 18.488%;
  z-index: 2;

  /* moved your iphone image to the outer container */
  background-image: url(http://s18.postimg.org/fzjmm7kih/iphone5.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.iphone > div {
  position: absolute;

  /* clip */
  top: 13%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 26%;
  left: 10%;

  /* i put your droplet image on the inner div */
  background-image: url(http://s16.postimg.org/vqs385e6t/background_leaf.jpg);

  /* positioning magic */
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

See demo at http://jsbin.com/ozoyoc/2/

Source: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/demo.html (created before the days of alpha-transparent colors or png support)

Comment: Thanks! Next step is to center the outer container and somehow get the correct offset and use it to add a background-position style. Tips on this?

Comment: @andy I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you update the demo so i can see how/where your attempt fails?

Comment: @andy as long as you have the same `background-position` on both the background of the container and the background of the iphone, the fixed attachment should take care of the rest http://jsbin.com/ozoyoc/4